# Angular http post failure response for http://localhost:8080/user/login: 500 OK

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an api service which communicates with the api. It looks like this

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
    private headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    });

  constructor(
      private http: HttpClient,
      private alertService: AlertService,
      private router: Router
  ) { }

  public credentialsLogin(request: UserCredentialsRequest) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(request));
      return this.http
          .post(API_URL+"/user/login", JSON.stringify(request), {headers: this.headers})
          .map(
              (response) => {
                  this.handleResponseMessages(response);
                  return response;
              }
          ).catch((response) => this.handleError(response));
  }

  private handleResponseMessages(response:any) {
      console.log(response.headers);
      const messages: [{messageContent, messageType}] = response.messages;

      if(messages != null && messages.length > 0) {
            this.alertService.parseAlerts(messages);
      }
  }

  private handleError (response: Response | any) {
      console.log(response);
      if(response != null && response.error != null) {
          const error = response.error;

          if(error.messages != null && error.messages.length > 0) {
              const errorMessages = error.messages;
                  this.alertService.parseAlerts(errorMessages);
          }
      }

      //this.router.navigate(['../']);

      return Observable.throw(response);

  }

}
```

The userservice from where I call the api service

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService{
  activeUser: UserModel;
  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

  credentialsLogin(data:{username, password}) {
      console.log(data);
      const request = new UserCredentialsRequest(data.username, data.password);
      this.api.credentialsLogin(request)
          .subscribe(
              (response) => {
                  console.log(response);
              }
          );
  }
}
```

I call the credentialsLogin user service method from component where I just pass data from the form. I think I do not need to paste component code here, that logic works just fine according to the console of objects passing to api.

When I call the credentialsLogin with proper object (it contains just username and password as string) I get the **http failure response for http://localhost:8080/user/login: 500 OK** error.

The bug must be in the angular. Cause when I copy the `JSON.stringify(request)` to the Restlet Client in my browser and send post request with that data, I get the proper answers (success login, no data sent, invalid username or password).

Does anybody where should be the mistake?

Comment: Can you try by sending request without using `JSON.stringify` in api service. In which language you have written server side?

Comment: I solved it by adding `let responseBody: {} = JSON.stringify(request);` and pass this variable to the post method. I dont know why but its working. Thank for your help.

Comment: It's because `POST` method of http requires param as JSON object not string.